uninitialized shadow variables are not filtered when using optaplanner
When I used shadow variables, a null pointer exception occurred during the score calculation.
I remember that in the optaplanner documentation, planning variables that were not assigned a value would be automatically filtered out.
What I want to achieve is that when the planning variables of ComposeCourseClazz change, the planning variables of CourseClazz also change accordingly.
my code
Planning entities: 

@PlanningEntity
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id")
public class ComposeCourseClazz {
   
   @PlanningId
   private String id;

   @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = {"slots"})
   private Timeslot slot;

   @ValueRangeProvider(id = "slots")
   private List<Timeslot> slotList;
   
   private List<CourseClazz> ccList;
   ...
}

@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id")
@PlanningEntity
public class CourseClazz {

    @PlanningId
    private String id;

    @ShadowVariable(variableListenerClass = SlotUpdatingVariableListener.class,
            sourceEntityClass = ComposeCourseClazz.class, sourceVariableName = "slot")
    private Timeslot slot;
    ...
}

Listener:
public class SlotUpdatingVariableListener implements VariableListener<CourseSchedule, ComposeCourseClazz> {
  @Override
    public void afterVariableChanged(ScoreDirector<CourseSchedule> scoreDirector, ComposeCourseClazz composeCourseClazz) {
        updateSlotForCC(scoreDirector, composeCourseClazz);
        
    }

    @Override
    public void afterEntityAdded(ScoreDirector<CourseSchedule> scoreDirector, ComposeCourseClazz composeCourseClazz) {
        updateSlotForCC(scoreDirector, composeCourseClazz);
    }
    protected void updateSlotForCC(ScoreDirector<CourseSchedule> scoreDirector, ComposeCourseClazz composeCourseClazz) {
        Timeslot slot = composeCourseClazz.getSlot();
        for (CourseClazz cc : composeCourseClazz.getCcList()) {
            scoreDirector.beforeVariableChanged(cc, "slot");
            cc.setSlot(slot);
            scoreDirector.afterVariableChanged(cc, "slot");
        }
    }
}


exception message:
org.drools.modelcompiler.constraints.ConstraintEvaluationException: Error evaluating constraint '' in  and in more rules
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.constraints.LambdaConstraint.isAllowed(LambdaConstraint.java:184) ~[drools-model-compiler-8.44.0.Final.jar:8.44.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.phreak.PhreakAccumulateNode.propagateResult(PhreakAccumulateNode.java:665) ~[drools-core-8.44.0.Final.jar:8.44.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.phreak.PhreakGroupByNode.evaluateResultConstraints(PhreakGroupByNode.java:75) ~[drools-core-8.44.0.Final.jar:8.44.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.phreak.PhreakAccumulateNode.doNode(PhreakAccumulateNode.java:109) ~[drools-core-8.44.0.Final.jar:8.44.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.switchOnDoBetaNode(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:593) ~[drools-core-8.44.0.Final.jar:8.44.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.evalBetaNode(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:562) ~[drools-core-8.44.0.Final.jar:8.44.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.evalNode(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:389) ~[drools-core-8.44.0.Final.jar:8.44.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.innerEval(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:349) ~[drools-core-8.44.0.Final.jar:8.44.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.evalStackEntry(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:247) ~[drools-core-8.44.0.Final.jar:8.44.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.outerEval(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:190) ~[drools-core-8.44.0.Final.jar:8.44.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.evaluateNetwork(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:143) ~[drools-core-8.44.0.Final.jar:8.44.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleExecutor.evaluateNetwork(RuleExecutor.java:221) ~[drools-core-8.44.0.Final.jar:8.44.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleExecutor.evaluateNetworkIfDirty(RuleExecutor.java:231) ~[drools-core-8.44.0.Final.jar:8.44.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleExecutor.evaluateNetworkAndFire(RuleExecutor.java:76) ~[drools-core-8.44.0.Final.jar:8.44.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.concurrent.AbstractGroupEvaluator.evaluateAndFire(AbstractGroupEvaluator.java:46) ~[drools-core-8.44.0.Final.jar:8.44.0.Final]
    at org.drools.kiesession.agenda.DefaultAgenda.fireLoop(DefaultAgenda.java:624) ~[drools-kiesession-8.44.0.Final.jar:8.44.0.Final]
    at org.drools.kiesession.agenda.DefaultAgenda.internalFireAllRules(DefaultAgenda.java:571) ~[drools-kiesession-8.44.0.Final.jar:8.44.0.Final]
    at org.drools.kiesession.agenda.DefaultAgenda.fireAllRules(DefaultAgenda.java:563) ~[drools-kiesession-8.44.0.Final.jar:8.44.0.Final]
    at org.drools.kiesession.session.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.internalFireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1088) ~[drools-kiesession-8.44.0.Final.jar:8.44.0.Final]
    at org.drools.kiesession.session.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.fireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1079) ~[drools-kiesession-8.44.0.Final.jar:8.44.0.Final]
    at org.drools.kiesession.session.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.fireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1071) ~[drools-kiesession-8.44.0.Final.jar:8.44.0.Final]
    at org.optaplanner.constraint.streams.drools.DroolsConstraintStreamScoreDirector.calculateScore(DroolsConstraintStreamScoreDirector.java:70) ~[optaplanner-constraint-streams-drools-9.44.0.Final.jar:9.44.0.Final]
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.recaller.BestSolutionRecaller.solvingStarted(BestSolutionRecaller.java:50) ~[optaplanner-core-impl-9.44.0.Final.jar:9.44.0.Final]
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.AbstractSolver.solvingStarted(AbstractSolver.java:65) ~[optaplanner-core-impl-9.44.0.Final.jar:9.44.0.Final]
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.solvingStarted(DefaultSolver.java:225) ~[optaplanner-core-impl-9.44.0.Final.jar:9.44.0.Final]
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.solve(DefaultSolver.java:192) ~[optaplanner-core-impl-9.44.0.Final.jar:9.44.0.Final]
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolverJob.call(DefaultSolverJob.java:109) ~[optaplanner-core-impl-9.44.0.Final.jar:9.44.0.Final]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:317) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589) ~[na:na]

in the scoring function, I filter out unassigned shadow variables. And adding new the penalty function that penalizes unassigned shadow variables.

Although not a direct answer to your question, you may want to check out Timefold Solver - a well maintained fork of OptaPlanner. It includes almost 15 months' worth of new features and bug fixes compared to the OptaPlanner codebase, and the exception you are mentioning is not even possible there.
You may even benefit from cascading update shadow variable, a recently introduced feature which greatly simplifies updates to tail chains and helps users avoid mistakes when implementing variable listeners.

When I switched to timefold, the problem still occurred. It looks like there's something wrong with my understanding of shadow variables.  Is the shadow variables  not automatically filtered in constraint stream evaluation function?

The problem could not have occurred, because the code in question (org.drools.modelcompiler.constraints.ConstraintEvaluationException) physically does not exist in Timefold Solver. You are probably running into a similar problem, but not the same one. Since you haven't shared your constraints, I can not answer in detail, but yes - foreach et al. will not look at shadow variables when filtering out null. That only applies to uninitialized entities - and null shadow variables have nothing to do with entity initialization.
